# Return Vec mut ref trait objects from Vec

Tags: vector, rust, traits, trait-objects

I am trying to implement part of a UI framework. In the bottom example, the impl of `widgets_mut()` for `Vec<T>` needs to return a vector of trait objects like `Vec<&mut dyn AnyWidget>`. Given T is constrained to impl `AnyWidget` I don't understand why I am getting the error:

```
a value of type `Vec<&mut dyn AnyWidget>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&mut T`
the trait `FromIterator<&mut T>` is not implemented for `Vec<&mut dyn AnyWidget>`
```

Why does the 2-tuple implementation work, but the Vec implementation which seems equivalent doesn't?

```rust
fn main() {}

pub trait AnyWidget {}

pub trait WidgetVec {
    fn widgets_mut(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut dyn AnyWidget>;
}

// This implementation for a 2-tuple seems equivalent and works fine:
impl<W0: AnyWidget, W1: AnyWidget> WidgetVec for (W0, W1) {
    fn widgets_mut(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut dyn AnyWidget> {
        let mut v: Vec<&mut dyn AnyWidget> = Vec::with_capacity(2);
        v.push(&mut self.0);
        v
    }
}

impl<T: AnyWidget> WidgetVec for Vec<T> {
    fn widgets_mut(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut dyn AnyWidget> {
        self.iter_mut()
            .map(|child| child)
            .collect::<Vec<&mut dyn AnyWidget>>()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to cast `child` to `&mut dyn AnyWidget`. E.g. change `.map(|child| child)` to `.map(|child| child as &mut dyn AnyWidget)` or even just to `.map(|child| child as _)`, and the code compiles.

Comment: awesome, thanks. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: This is a very frequent (and sadly quite unnecessary) stumbling block with dynamic dispatch, so there are probably a bunch of dups. Now that someone has written one, it's fine to accept it, you don't need to wait for one from me.

Comment: Also note that you don't need turbofish (explicit `::<Vec<...>>()` in the call to `collect()` - since the function already has the return type spelled out, a simple `.collect()` will work just as nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're missing is to explicitly cast the `child` from `&mut T` to `&mut dyn AnyWidget`.

```
impl<T: AnyWidget> WidgetVec for Vec<T> {
    fn widgets_mut(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut dyn AnyWidget> {
        self.iter_mut()
            .map(|child| child as &mut dyn AnyWidget)
            .collect::<Vec<&mut dyn AnyWidget>>()
    }
}
```

In some cases, rust will perform these kinds of conversions automatically (at "coercion sites"), but this can't be done here, because there isn't a coercion site where you're trying to cast `child`. See the reference on [coercion sites](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-sites) for all the places this can be done.